# Why is an object considered less buoyant if it is fully submerged?

Tags: forces, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, buoyancy

I found the following on BYJUS:
A body experiences greater buoyant force when it is fully submerged compared to when it is partially.

https://byjus.com/question-answer/a-body-experiences-greater-buoyant-force-when-it-is-fully-submerged-compared-to-when-it/

The statement above is false, due to the following explanation:
Buoyant force acting on an object, whether it is fully submerged or partially submerged, is equal to the weight of the fluid displaced. So, the buoyant force is not defined as the weight of the body, nor is it the part of the weight of the body submerged.

I don't understand why an object that is fully submerged is less buoyant, because if it is fully submerged, doesn't it displace more fluid, so won't it be more buoyant?

Comment: Welcome Sophie.  What is "BYJUS"? If quoting an online source, it is always best to give a link.

Comment: Oh sorry, updated the question to include the link

Answer (score 5):

This is correct:

> Buoyant force acting on an object, whether it is fully submerged or partially submerged, is equal to the weight of the fluid displaced.

If a body is fully submerged, then it typically displaces more fluid than it does when it is partially submerged.

(Note: this is not universal, and for there to be a guarantee that this will happen the body needs to be convex. A simple counterexample is a boat, which displaces all of the internal volume of the hold when it is floating, but only the volume of the boat itself once it drinks. But that is clearly not what the text is addressing. So, for the purposes of the text, if a body is only partially submerged, it displaces less fluid than when fully submerged.)

Therefore, as the text says,

> A body experiences greater buoyant force when it is fully submerged compared to when it is partially.

Note that the statement is only talking about the buoyant force experienced by the object, and not about whether the object is more buoyant or not, which is a vaguer concept.

Comment: If i have a less buoyant heavier object that is fully submerged, and a more buoyant lighter object of identical volume that is initially also fully submerged, both experience identical buoyant force since volume of fluid displaced is equal? Eventually, since buoyant force exceeds weight for the more buoyant lighter object, it rises until it becomes partially submerged. As it rises, buoyant force decreases since volume of fluid displaced decreases, so at the end of the day, does this more buoyant lighter object experience less buoyant force than the heavier object which remains fully submerged?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who has ever tried to push a beach ball under water can certainly testify that the buoyant force greatly increases as you try to submerge it.  The [BYJUS](https://byjus.com/question-answer/a-body-experiences-greater-buoyant-force-when-it-is-fully-submerged-compared-to-when-it/) answer could only make sense is they have a very weird definition of "buoyant force".

Comment: In what case would byjus answer make sense then?

Comment: They don't say buoyancy but "buoyant force". So it is not a matter of defining "buoyancy". Their "explanation" is nonsense. I am talking about the link, not about the answer by David Bailey.

Comment: Thanks @nasu. I found the the [same question with the same wrong answer in a book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=RUJjDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA187) but without the nonsense explanation, so it may originally have just been a typo. Maybe BYJUS asked [ChatGPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT) to explain the answer:).

Comment: @Sophie-Lee I could try to make something up that might work semantically,  but that would at best just transfer the nonsense from the explanation to the definition.  You should be proud that you figured out yourself that the answer and explanation didn't make sense. When a book, site, or scientific paper has a mistake, it can waste a lot of the reader's time before we realize it is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The only way an object can be considered less buoyant when fully submerged than when partially submerged is if the object has a convex shape, such as a boat hull or an upright bucket. In this case, the object actually displaces *less* water when it is fully submerged than when it is partially submerged, so the buoyancy force on the fully submerged object is less than when it is partially submerged. Which is why (most) boats float on the surface but sink if they are fully submerged.

Note that the buoyancy force on an object depends on the geometry of the object and the extent to which it is submerged (which determines the volume of water displaced) but does not depend on the mass of the object itself.